# Selection shows in Attributes but not on web map served by ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-online, select

In ArcGIS Online webGIS, I created a map application. I have a particular layer that if I were to try to select an object within that layer, the selection displays in the attributes table, it displays as being selected in the Select widget (a 1 next to the layer), but the object is not highlighted on the map.

I've gone through the .mxd for the service, and Selection> Interactive Selection Method is selected at Create new Selection. I reconfirmed that the layer is selectable and I've re-published the service.

I'm not having this issue with the other layers that I've hosted in this web app. For whatever reason, it just doesn't show the selection on the production version.

How do I fix it?

Comment: I've assumed that you are using ArcGIS Server.  If not, then please [edit] your question to provide more details about exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Correct, we are using an ArcGIS Server.